# Link creation plugin JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

does anybody know of a JS/jQuery plugin or script that enables the creation of links, in a way similar to the way Github does it in their text editor, e.g.

```
[Text to display](http://url.com)
```

would turn into: [Text to display](http://url.com)

I would like to use this kind of functionality in a textarea where the user can include custom links.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Github uses a superset of markdown. https://github.com/chjj/marked

Comment: Felix, you are fast!

Comment: There is a list of javascript wysiwyg editors here - https://github.com/cheeaun/mooeditable/wiki/Javascript-WYSIWYG-editors. They should have something like this plus a whole lot more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use markdown.js for this
https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js

Comment: Or something like https://github.com/chjj/marked
Marked should be even better than markdown-js, looks like a better repo

Answer (score 1):

Like the other said there are a lot of plugins you can use. If you only need to transform the texts you gave as example to a link, you can use something simple like:

```
var urlParts = '[Text to display](http://url.com)'.match(/\[(.*)\]\((.*)\)/);
console.log('<a href="' + urlParts[2] + '">' + urlParts[1] + '</a>');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zu17cy3/)

Comment: thanks a lot for your help!